# Creating a log for intensive data operation

Tags: c++, msmq

I have an intensive data operation of huge amount which is being processed by my application. This process usually takes 12 hours to complete.
  Recently i faced some problems in it and i made some functions to log files on the disc.
  But its a worst decision i have ever taken. This application is taking 48 hours now( 4 times greater).

Is there any way to create log without compromising with the performance ? I have heard of MSMQ messages etc. What are the different options ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is your log? Maybe you should form it entirely in memory, and write do disk after the process done?

Comment: Hi Ryzhen thanks for looking into it , Its close to 7 Gbs

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the workload and the amount of logging, asynchronous logger may be of help. Implementing one yourself is not entirely trivial though. I've used [g2log](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288827/g-log-An-efficient-asynchronous-logger-using-Cplus) before.